Existence of uniformly convergent sequence of polynomials converging to an analytic function
Let $\Delta_1,\Delta_2,\dotsc,\Delta_n$ be mutually disjoint open discs in the complex plane.
Question part 1: Does there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converging uniformly on every compact subset of $\cup_{i}\Delta_i$ to an analytic function? Why or why not?
A paper of Douglas and Percy, Von Neumann algebras with a single generator (page 22), references a theorem of Lavrentiev in Sur les fonctions d'une variable complexe repr'{e}sentables par des s'{e}ries de polynomes that asserts the positive. However, I cannot find this latter document to look at the proof.
Question part 2: Assuming a positive answer to part 1, can we find such a sequence converging to the particular analytic function
[
f(z) = \begin{cases}
 1,& z \in \Delta_1\\
0,& z \in \bigcup_{i=2}^n\Delta_i
\end{cases}?
]

Hint: Runge's theorem.  Yes, any analytic function on $\bigcup_i \Delta_i$ can be the limit.

Unless $\Delta_1$ or $\Delta_2\cup\dots \cup\Delta_n$ is empty, there is no such analytic function as asked for in part 2. Any analytic function that vanishes on a non-empty open subset must be identically zero by the identity theorem.

$\Delta_1,\Delta_2,\dotsc,\Delta_n$ are mutually disjoint open discs in the complex plane

At the direction of Robert Israel in the comments, we have the following answer.
This is a simple application of Runge's theorem. Consider the statement of this theorem in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (Theorem 13.9):
Let $S^2$ be the Riemann sphere; let $\Omega$ be an open set in the plane; let $A$ be a set which has one point in each component of $S^2\setminus \Omega$; let $f$ be analytic on $\Omega$. Then there is a sequence $(R_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of rational functions, with poles only in $A$, such that $R_n \to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$. In particular, when $S^2 \setminus \Omega$ is connected, we may take $A = \{\infty\}$ so that there is a sequence $(P_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of polynomials such that $P_n \to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$.
Thus, taking $\Omega = \cup_{i}\Delta_i$ as in the question statement, clearly $S^2 \setminus \Omega$ is connected. So for the specific function defined in the question, we can take $A = \{\infty\}$ as in the theorem and obtain a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$ to $f$.
